# Can I know the best way to render template Client side Vs Server side using Express? And performance?

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express, ejs

It's getting difficult day by day to choose server side Vs client side rendering, can some one post ur thoughts or references on this??

Which one will give better performance ??

Answer (score 0):

- Bandwidth:  In my mind, the less data you have to push to the client the faster everything will seem to your users, assuming that you've scaled the server-side appropriately.  This tends to suggest server-side rendering.
- Security:  I tend to "keep my cards close to my chest" when playing poker and in design terms that means that the less API you expose to the browser's View -> Source, the better, IMHO.  Again, I like to render things on the server if I can.
- Third-party:  If I'm exercising a well-known third-party API like Google Maps then it doesn't matter to me if I'm doing that client- or server-side with the exception of exposing a Google API key, for example.  There may be some advantages to pushing this client-side when Google is tracking the hits-per-second or whatever; you'd be using the client's IP address instead of your own.
- Moving Target:  If you're pushing a lot of code to the browser, to include modules, then you can never guarantee what browser the client will have.  What's to prevent a new browser version from coming out tomorrow?  How will your new stack work on that until you've tested it?  Server-side, **I** control that platform, usually at least.

In a nutshell, I do server when I can.  AngularJS is pretty cool, though.  Things may change up as a result of it.  That's my take on it.